# Reading configuration section from a restricted appdomain

Tags: c#, permissions, appdomain, code-access-security

I have some configuration section defined in a signed assembly A, that are used in an app domain that loads its own configuration file, created by the assembly A.

The assembly loaded B is not a full trust application.

All assemblies are written using .Net 4.

The assembly security is managed using PermissionSet.

The problem is that the domain created is not able to access the section, resulting in a SecurityException "Request Failed."
The action demanded is : `<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>`

I already tried to give lots of permissions, without any effects :

```
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission(ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlEvidence));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlPolicy));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter));
        System.Configuration.Configuration cnf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, cnf.FilePath));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.GacIdentityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.PublisherIdentityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.StrongNameIdentityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.TypeDescriptorPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.UrlIdentityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permSet.AddPermission(new System.Security.Permissions.ZoneIdentityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

I try to access the section like this :

```
(MySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mySectionGroup/mySection")
```

And like this :

```
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var config = (DictionaryConfigurationSection)configuration.GetSection("agent/dictionaries");
```

The section is defined with the requirePermission set to false.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In fact, ConfigurationSections were defined in a full trust assembly. So the partial trust caller could not read the configuration section, even if the require permission = false was present. 
I found a workaround, mark the assembly that contains the configuration section definition with this attribute : AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers